# Removing white paint in unglazed side of tile?

Tags: tile, ceramic-tile

What's all this white in the unglazed side of the tile?

Most important, how can I easily remove it?

Btw it's in all the tiles of the home depot that I visited today.

[image]

Comment: Why remove it?  It is on the back side never to be seen once the tile is placed.  If on all the tiles, probably made that way.

Comment: Strange byproduct of glazing, probably. Leave it.

Comment: Looks like all the spots with white are high and not low. I would think it is glaze that got on the bottom from where the tile rides a conveyor when going under the glazing spray/waterfall. I've seen that on almost all glazed tile I've looked at and never gave it a second thought because that is the bottom that you can't see when they are layed.

Comment: One of you could turn that in to an answer. Agreed: it's nothing to even think about.

Comment: It is of no consequences, but out of curiosity, why is there a desire to remove it?

Comment: That's what these [tile rubbing stones](https://images.thdstatic.com/productImages/ca766cdd-416c-4f1b-aa15-e6bab686d5e2/svn/qep-grout-remover-tools-10022-64_300.jpg) are for - removing all that paint from the back side of tiles! ;)

Comment: @crip659: that's because you assume I'll be using it on the floor.

Comment: Unless they are put on a window or used as drink coasters/pot holders the back side is never seen again on floors/walls/ceilings.

Answer (score 4):

Consensus from comments: this is just a byproduct of manufacturing and will not be seen in the finished installation. Don’t worry about it.